# Rails - Update title while incrementing through rows in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, list, increment

In my view, I want to generate a set number of rows in a list. The set number of times is represented by the chosen_award attribute in the following code:

```
                <%= current_user.chosen_award.times do %>
                   <li class="list-group-item">
                     <a href="/personal_entry">Week *INCREMENT ME*</a>
                   </li>    
                <% end %>
```

I want to use the bootstrap list-group-item, but I need to create a different title for every row. For the first row I want the title to be Week 1, for the second row I want the title to be Week 2, for the third week the title should be Week 3 etc.

Can I do this in my rails view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. `.times` method has an index you can use

```
<% current_user.chosen_award.times do |index| %>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="/personal_entry">
      <%= "Week #{index + 1}" %>
    </a>
  </li>
<% end %>
```